# SQL Server calculation, how to modify?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce, ceil

We are doing the following sql server calculation:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(ceiling(xm.datapoints / 8) + 1, 1)
```

Problem is that we shouldn't always add + 1 to the ceiling value.

- If `xm.datapoints % 8 > 0` then we should add + 1.
- If `xm.datapoints % 8 = 0` we should not add + 1.

So how do we modify our query so + 1 is only added `ix xm.datapoints % 8 > 0` ?

Thanks.

Comment: I see 3 left but 2 right parenthesis. Please correct.

Comment: That looks off. Ceiling rounds up, so it already naturally "adds" 1 when `xm.datapoints % 8 > 1`. If it were the other way around, I'd tell you to use `FLOOR` and *always* add 1, but as it is, using `CASE` is just about the only thing I can think of as well.

Comment: It looks off to me as well. If your function is called _f_ then _f_ (NULL)=1, _f_ (0)=0, _f_ (1)=2 ... _f_ (8)=2, _f_ (9) = 3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `xm.datapoints` is an integer so the division result is truncated. Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(ceiling(xm.datapoints / 8.0), 0.0)))
```

or if you want to use integer arithmetic only:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(1+(xm.datapoints-1)/8, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(case when (xm.datapoints % 8 > 0) 
                         then ceiling((xm.datapoints % 8) + 1)
                         when xm.datapoints % 8 = 0 
                         ceiling(xm.datapoints % 8 end), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(CEILING(xm.datapoints / 8) 
                    + CASE WHEN xm.datapoints % 8 > 0 THEN 1 
                                                      ELSE 0 END, 1))
```

You needed an extra closing bracket too, but that was probably a copy & paste error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`SELECT SUM(COALESCE(ceiling(xm.datapoints / 8) + (CASE WHEN xm.datapoints %8 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 1))`

Answer (score 0):

You could treat `0` as `NULL` with [`NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx):

```
SELECT COALESCE(CEILING(NULLIF(@xmdatapoints, 0) / 8) + 1, 1)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12253/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In case that is related to what you want to achieve: if you want to round *DOWN* to the nearest value divisible by 8 you can use this little bit of bitwise magic:

```
SELECT xm.datapoints & (~ 7)
```

Maybe it helps...